# Open link in new window, but make it just like opening in original window

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an index.php that loads a page.php into a #result div. Page.php in turn has its own links and I have it so that when you click on one of these links it loads the respective page into the SAME #result div. Similarly that loaded page might have its own links and I want to continue loading content into the same div. The code for this is as follows:

```
function loadPage(url){
       $("#wrapper").load(url, function(){
            $("#wrapper").find($('a')).each(function(){
                 $(this).on('click', function(e){
                    loadPage($(this).attr('href'));
                    e.preventDefault();
                 });
            });
        });
    }
```

Say page.php has a link to page2.php.

At the moment when I open the link to page2.php in a new window, it opens as page2.php. Same if I type the url to page2.php directly into my browser. I want it so that it opens as index.php but with page2.php loaded into its #result div(a duplicate of clicking the link normally in the original window).

How do you do this?? I have tried lots of things including setting a session variable and passing to loadPage, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: you want to reform your result div by ajax request?

Comment: When i open page2.php in a new window, i want it to load index.php with page2.php loaded in result div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was on the right track with setting the session variable!!!

In index.php, just after you start your session, you have to check whether the session variable has been set. If not, set it to page.php i.e.

```
 if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])) 
     $_SESSION['id'] = "page.php";
```

Then in page2.php, immediately after you set up the session, set the session variable to page2.php. i.e.

```
 $_SESSION['id'] = "page2.php";
```

Also you have to set it in your login.php before you redirect to index.php.

If you set up the 'id' session variable to the right pages in the right places, you should get the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

you want to reform your result div by ajax request? if it is, so use

```
jQuery.ajax(url,[settings]) ;
```

Comment: this link is good to read http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/   this is about how $ajax work. I explain a bit: if you click somewhere so you want your result div to be filled with some html from,say page2.php, but your url remains page.php. something like this

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function loadPage(url){
   $.get(url, function(data){
       $("#wrapper").empty().append(data);
       $("#wrapper body").find('a').each(function(){
         $(this).click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           loadPage( $(this).attr('href') );
         });
       });
   });
}
```

Comment: it works worse than it did before! in that, it now doesn't load page2.php in the main window #result div when you click on a link. It still simply loads page2.php when you open the link in a new window.

Comment: Does page.php/page2.php have html,head and body tags?

Comment: You may want to consider using an `iframe` instead of a `div#wrapper`

Comment: Or try adding the `body` tag in your selecter, see updated code.